# How to create Setup with Input Information

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clr, installation

can anyone tell me how to make Setup Project for CLR, which will take Connection String  Parameters. 
I want my Clr to run under any SQL server, can anyone advice how to pass parameters to Setup project and how to make my clr get where to connect. 
Or is there any other way to deploy CLR dll without source to another Server?

Answer (score -1):

I did some research and read, that CLR can run without Setup project, I mean, if someone has CLR and wants to run it on different servers, just is needed to build CLR and get dll, then to add that dll on assambly (with external-access) and then to create stored procedure in wanted database `CREATE PROCEDURE GetBranches
AS
EXTERNAL NAME SolutionName.ClassName.ProcedureName`

that's all :) pretty simple